# How does one create a method to add things in a list in Python?

Tags: java, python

My background is in Java and I was only recently learning how to do some object oriented programming in it. I am currently learning python as well and I wondering how this Java code translates into python.

Assuming I have a HockeyPlayer class that has a jerseyNumber instance variable:

```
public void addPlayer(HockeyPlayer h){
   if(hockeyPlayers == null){
      hockeyPlayers = new ArrayList<HockeyPlayer>();
   }
   if(jerseyNumberExists(h.getJerseyNumber()) == false){
       // this jersey number is available; add the player
       hockeyPlayers.add(h);
   }
}
```

Comment: How about you read a tutorial on Python first? - [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `append()` method to append a single item to your list.

```
>>> hockeyplayers = ["Adam", "Ben"]
>>> hockeyplayers.append("Charlie")
>>> hockeyplayers
['Adam', 'Ben', 'Charlie']
```

To concatenate two lists, use the `extend()` method:

```
>>> moreplayers = ["Dan", "Eddie"]
>>> hockeyplayers.extend(moreplayers)
>>> hockeyplayers
['Adam', 'Ben', 'Charlie', 'Dan', 'Eddie']
```

It's irrelevant what kinds of objects your lists contains, by the way.